# List all values in same row in a view

Tags: 8, views

I have a view that displays the authors of an article and links to their author page.

Currently the view outputs each author in its own row as a list. I'd like to have it display the authors in one row separated by commas.

It's currently outputting like this:

Suzanne Smith

Jack Johnson

Alex Anderson

I'd like it to output like this:
Suzanne Smith, Jack Johnson, Alex Anderson

I came across this question which recommended using the Views Aggregator Plus module, which I have installed. However the screenshots don't work. https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2019-09-19/struggling-to-list-all-values-in-field-on-same-row-in

Can anyone help with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you have your view configured to make it display each author in a new row?

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying the Article's Author field in your view, i.e. by setting
*Format > Show* to "Fields", you can configure your field to display all values in the same row. Click on the field (to edit its settings) and expand the "Multiple Field Settings" section. Check the "Display all values in the same row" checkbox.

[image: Image showing the "Multiple Field Settings" section of a Field's settings in the Views UI with the "Display all values in the same row" checkbox checked]